# Identity Server 4 & Protecting Internal reserved roles

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Imagine, an API would allow a 3rd party to set claims and roles for users, resources that they own. 
What would be the correct way to protect specific internal roles (say, our roles) being set on claims and or roles using Identity Server 4?

Thanks for sharing ideas how to do this correctly.

Comment: Do you want to protect your API with an IdentityServer4 generated token? Or did you want to host the API from the same server that implements the IdentityServer4 framework?

Comment: The token is ID4 generated indeed. 
Users can set their own claims. So this means, change their profile. So, imagine, they would be able to use Postman and postback to our API: "My claim is role='admin'".

The policies on ASP.NET Core do nocheck this. So I need to make 'ifs' based on the claimtypes being set. E.g. if I already possess a claim with role and value admin, I can set certain priviliged roles.